# Python scrape value between static HTML tags containing static text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

This is my first post in this forum and i believe that this forum would answer my basic question here.

My requirement here consists of two steps.

1. In the first step, i need to extract the value "Paid Death Notice" based on the tag span and class c8 and c2 for the below html data where "DOCUMENT-TYPE:" text is static and it will always be there in my HTML.

```html
<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Death Notice</SPAN></P>
```

similarly for the below html data, i need to extract "Newspaper" value based on "PUBLICATION TYPE" with span and class as c8 and c2

```html
<SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN>
```

**Solution i have tried:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = """<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">**Paid Death Notice**</SPAN>
           <SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
doc=soup.find('span',class_='c8')
doctext=re.compile('<SPAN(.*DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN.*?)</SPAN>')
print(doctext.match(doc.text))
```

**Result:**

```
None
```

Where i should get only **Paid Death Notice** as result

2. Similarly there could be many HTMl tags having same DOCUMENT-TYPE: field where it differs by value only, so in this case, how will i iterate the loop based under what condition?

```html
<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT</SPAN>
```

Pls help me to resolve the issue.

Note: I have searched in the web and tried many ways but cannot able to find right solution and i am finally posting here with the hope that i may get right solution for my question.

Comment: Don't use snippet for HTML code blocks. Just use this line above your HTML code. <!-- language: lang-html -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

data = """<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">**Paid Death Notice**</SPAN>
           <SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN>
           <SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT</SPAN>
           """
pattern="\<SPAN CLASS=\"c8\"\>DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS=\"c2\"\>(.*)\</SPAN>"
print [a.strip("*") for a in re.findall(pattern,data)]
```

Output:

```
['Paid Death Notice', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT']
```

Comment: I think i did not asked my question correctly. My actual question here is if the given html tag is "<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">**Paid Death Notice**</SPAN>" I need to get Paid Death Notice as output that i will store into a variable in order to import that variable data to DB later. If i select based on .c2 i will get many values and not a single value. ie. if i extract based on Document type, i will get value"Paid Death Notice"  which i will store into a variable. similarly if i extract Newspaperbased on Publication Type,which i will store into another variable

Comment: Check now. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Not exactly. I mean if i give DOCUMENT-TYPE along with span and class c8 and c2, i need to get "Paid Death Notice" text as output alone.Similarly i also need to get Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What is the Document-Type for which you want the c8 and c2 selected?

Comment: I mean to say as long as"<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">" as the beginning tag
"</SPAN>" as the ending tag,
and extract " Paid Death Notice" and "Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT" as outputs

Comment: You can get it without beautifulsoup. Because your pattern is strict. Check now.

Comment: can you tell me how will i do that for the above html data. I tried using regexp. but not getting correct results

Comment: Where is your HTML data coming from? Give me the complete problem. You are providing information piece by piece.

Comment: <BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">URL: </SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LANGUAGE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">ENGLISH</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Death Notice</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">SUBJECT: </SPAN>

Comment: Sample HTML data above. I cannot post full HTML data as data is huge.Here for Language: I need to get English as result and store into one variable, Similarly for Document-Type result as " Paid death notice " in another variable, Publication-Type result as "Newspaper into another variable etc.,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Somehow the above solution works with less modification according to my requirement

Comment: You are welcome. Read this on how to ask your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks. Now there is specific scenario, where i need to extract text in between the tags .<DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">TICKER: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CATR (PAR) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (SWX) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (NYSE) (70%)</SPAN></P>. Here i need CATR (PAR) (70%); CAT (SWX) (70%);CAT (NYSE) (70%);

Comment: Here the Ticker is alone static and other text and tags are not static as before.Another eg:<SPAN CLASS="c8">TICKER: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">DUPP (PAR) (93%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c4">DD</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (NYSE) (93%)</SPAN>. Could you pls help me, how to solve this scenario

Comment: Please post it as a separate question and it should be complete and verifiable. And also include your broken code that is not working.

Comment: Pls find my separate post for the question in the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40929609/python-scrape-text-between-htm-tags-continuation-topic

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">**Paid Death Notice**</SPAN>
       <SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
doc = soup.find('span',class_='c8')
print(doc.text)
```

Result:

```
DOCUMENT-TYPE:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findall method from re module, and regular expression.

Example:

```
import re
data = """<SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">**Paid Death Notice**</SPAN>
       <SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN>
       <SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT</SPAN>
       """
data = data.replace('\n',' ')
res = re.findall("""<SPAN *CLASS="c8"> *([^:<]+): *</SPAN> *<SPAN *CLASS="c2">([^<]*)</SPAN>""", 
             data, 
             re.IGNORECASE
    )
print res
print "\n".join([ "%s: %s" % (item[0],item[1]) for item in res ])
```

Output:
`[('DOCUMENT-TYPE', '**Paid Death Notice**'), ('PUBLICATION-TYPE', 'Newspaper'), ('DOCUMENT-TYPE', 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT')]
DOCUMENT-TYPE: **Paid Death Notice**
PUBLICATION-TYPE: Newspaper
DOCUMENT-TYPE: Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT`

You can simply get the res variable and get all keys and values.
If you would like to convert the result to dictionary you can use this code:

```
res_dict = dict(res)
print res_dict
```

but in that case, the first 'DOCUMENT-TYPE' occurrence will be overrided, by the last one:

```
{'DOCUMENT-TYPE': 'Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT', 'PUBLICATION-TYPE': 'Newspaper'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though i don't require it as dictionary. I learnt new way how to store it in dictionary format.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix regexes and BeautifulSoup, BS has enough methods to navigate DOM tree:

```
if doc.text.startswith('DOCUMENT-TYPE'):
    print doc.find_next_sibling().text

# prints **Paid Death Notice**
```

You can also iterate on all tags with particular property:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('span', class_='c8'):
    print tag.text

# DOCUMENT-TYPE:
# PUBLICATION-TYPE:
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the above method earlier but unfortunately it didn't work perfectly for my requirement

Comment: It's the best you can get from BS. Can you clarify what exactly is not working here?