# Python scrape text between htm tags continuation topic

Tags: python, html

All, 
This is continuation from [**my previous post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906144/python-scrape-value-between-static-html-tags-containing-static-text), but for different scenario.

Now there is specific scenario, where i need to extract text in between the tags.

```
    data='''<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">1 of 2 DOCUMENTS</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c3">March</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> 17, 2016 Thursday</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;<BR>Late Edition - Final</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c7">Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">SECTION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Section A; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 19</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LENGTH: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">176 words</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">THORNTON--Robert. Robert &quot;Bob&quot; Richard Thornton, 89, of Peoria, IL, died peacefully and surrounded by family on Friday, March 11, 2016. Bob was born October 16, 1926, in Jersey City, New Jersey. He graduated from Regis High School in New York City on June 15, 1945, and immediately thereafter served in the U.S. Navy. He received a B.A. from Georgetown University in 1950 and a J.D. from Columbia University Law School in 1953. He practiced law in New York City for 17 years with the law firms of Dorr Hand and Nixon, Mudge, Rose, Guthrie &amp; Alexander. He joined the legal department of Caterpillar Tractor Co. in 1970 and served as the company's General Counsel and Corporate Secretary from 1983 to 1991. He is survived by his wife, Dorothy (McGuire) of Peoria; and his children, Matthew, Nicholas, Jennifer, and Julia. In lieu of flowers, donations may be made in the name of Robert and Dorothy Thornton to St. Philomena's School in Peoria, IL, Regis High School in New York City, or the National Association for Rare Disorders (www.rare diseases.org). 1/3</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">URL: </SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LANGUAGE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">ENGLISH</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Death Notice</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">SUBJECT: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">DEATHS &amp; OBITUARIES (92%); HIGH SCHOOLS (90%); LAWYERS (87%); LAW SCHOOLS (77%); CORPORATE COUNSEL (75%); LEGAL SERVICES (70%); GRADUATE &amp; PROFESSIONAL SCHOOLS (70%); ASSOCIATIONS &amp; ORGANIZATIONS (65%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">COMPANY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CATERPILLAR INC (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">ORGANIZATION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">COLUMBIA UNIVERSITY (57%); GEORGETOWN UNIVERSITY (57%); US NAVY (57%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">TICKER: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CATR (PAR) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (SWX) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (NYSE) (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">INDUSTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NAICS333131 MINING MACHINERY &amp; EQUIPMENT MANUFACTURING (70%); NAICS333120 CONSTRUCTION MACHINERY MANUFACTURING (70%); NAICS333111 FARM MACHINERY &amp; EQUIPMENT MANUFACTURING (70%); SIC3531 CONSTRUCTION MACHINERY &amp; EQUIPMENT (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">PERSON: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">RICHARD NIXON (78%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">CITY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NEW YORK, NY, USA (94%); PEORIA, IL, USA (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">STATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NEW YORK, USA (94%); ILLINOIS, USA (94%); NEW JERSEY, USA (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">COUNTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">UNITED STATES (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LOAD-DATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">March 17, 2016</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Copyright 2016 The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> Company</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<!-- Hide XML section from browser
</DOCFULL>
</DOC> -->
<DIV CLASS="c10">&nbsp;</DIV>
<A NAME="DOC_ID_0_1"></A><!-- Hide XML section from browser
<DOC NUMBER=2>
<DOCFULL> -->
<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">2 of 2 DOCUMENTS</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times Company</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c3">March</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> 16, 2016 Wednesday</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;<BR>Late Edition - Final</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c7">Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">SECTION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Section B; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 16</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LENGTH: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">176 words</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">THORNTON--Robert. Robert &quot;Bob&quot; Richard Thornton, 89, of Peoria, IL, died peacefully and surrounded by family on Friday, March 11, 2016. Bob was born October 16, 1926, in Jersey City, New Jersey. He graduated from Regis High School in New York City on June 15, 1945, and immediately thereafter served in the U.S. Navy. He received a B.A. from Georgetown University in 1950 and a J.D. from Columbia University Law School in 1953. He practiced law in New York City for 17 years with the law firms of Dorr Hand and Nixon, Mudge, Rose, Guthrie &amp; Alexander. He joined the legal department of Caterpillar Tractor Co. in 1970 and served as the company's General Counsel and Corporate Secretary from 1983 to 1991. He is survived by his wife, Dorothy (McGuire) of Peoria; and his children, Matthew, Nicholas, Jennifer, and Julia. In lieu of flowers, donations may be made in the name of Robert and Dorothy Thornton to St. Philomena's School in Peoria, IL, Regis High School in New York City, or the National Association for Rare Disorders (www.rare diseases.org). 1/3 </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">URL: </SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LANGUAGE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">ENGLISH</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Death Notice</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">SUBJECT: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">DEATHS &amp; OBITUARIES (92%); HIGH SCHOOLS (90%); LAWYERS (87%); LAW SCHOOLS (77%); CORPORATE COUNSEL (75%); LEGAL SERVICES (70%); GRADUATE &amp; PROFESSIONAL SCHOOLS (70%); ASSOCIATIONS &amp; ORGANIZATIONS (65%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">COMPANY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CATERPILLAR INC (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">ORGANIZATION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">COLUMBIA UNIVERSITY (57%); GEORGETOWN UNIVERSITY (57%); US NAVY (57%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">TICKER: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CATR (PAR) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (SWX) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (NYSE) (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">INDUSTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NAICS333131 MINING MACHINERY &amp; EQUIPMENT MANUFACTURING (70%); NAICS333120 CONSTRUCTION MACHINERY MANUFACTURING (70%); NAICS333111 FARM MACHINERY &amp; EQUIPMENT MANUFACTURING (70%); SIC3531 CONSTRUCTION MACHINERY &amp; EQUIPMENT (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">PERSON: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">RICHARD NIXON (78%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">CITY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NEW YORK, NY, USA (94%); PEORIA, IL, USA (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">STATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NEW YORK, USA (94%); ILLINOIS, USA (94%); NEW JERSEY, USA (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">COUNTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">UNITED STATES (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LOAD-DATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">March 16, 2016</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Copyright 2015 The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> Company</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
```

'''

**Solution i have tried**:

```
publicationnamepattern="\<DIV CLASS=\"c0\"\>\<BR>\<P CLASS=\"c1\"\><SPAN CLASS=\"c2\"\>(.*)\</SPAN>\</P>"

copyrightpattern = "\<DIV CLASS=\"c0\"\>\<BR>\<P CLASS=\"c1\"\><SPAN CLASS=\"c2\"\>([^<]*)\</SPAN>"

publicationnamepatternvalues = [a.strip("*") for a in re.findall(publicationnamepattern, data)]

copyrightpatternvalues = [a.strip("*") for a in re.findall(copyrightpattern, data)]

print(str(publicationnamepatternvalues))

print(str(copyrightpatternvalues))
```

Result:

```
['The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times', 'Copyright 2016 The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> Company', 'The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times', 'Copyright 2016 The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> Company']
```

where i need only "**The New York Times**" for publicationnamepatternvalues and "**Copyright 2016 The New York Times  Company**" for Copyrightpatternvalues

I am not able to give more static values as only these fields are common in data.i.e New York Times

some data contain span class as c2 some contain c4 etc.,

Could anyone pls help me, how to solve this kind of scenario.

Comment: is there a reason you're using regex, rather than trying something like beautifulsoup?

Comment: Yep, rly try to learn the beatifulsoup - it great for things like this.

Comment: The reason i am using regexp and not Beautifulsoup  is some text are static always

Comment: If you use BeautifulSoup, could you pls provide me the solution for this as i dont find better solution using beautifulsoup

Comment: I hid the linked question in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a="""
data='''<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">1 of 2 DOCUMENTS</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c4"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c3">March</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> 17, 2016 Thursday</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;<BR>Late Edition - Final</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c7">Paid Notice: Deaths THORNTON, ROBERT</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">SECTION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Section A; Column 0; Classified; Pg. 19</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LENGTH: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">176 words</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c9"><SPAN CLASS="c2">THORNTON--Robert. Robert &quot;Bob&quot; 1/3</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">&nbsp;</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">URL: </SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LANGUAGE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">ENGLISH</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">DOCUMENT-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Paid Death Notice</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">PUBLICATION-TYPE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">Newspaper</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">SUBJECT: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">DEATHS &amp; OBITUARIES (92%); </SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">COMPANY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CATERPILLAR INC (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">ORGANIZATION: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">COLUMBIA UNIVERSITY (57%); GEORGETOWN UNIVERSITY (57%); US NAVY (57%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">TICKER: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">CATR (PAR) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (SWX) (70%); </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">CAT</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> (NYSE) (70%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">INDUSTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NAICS333131 MINING MACHINERY &amp; </SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">PERSON: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">RICHARD NIXON (78%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">CITY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NEW YORK, NY, USA (94%); PEORIA, IL, USA (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">STATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">NEW YORK, USA (94%); ILLINOIS, USA (94%); NEW JERSEY, USA (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">COUNTRY: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">UNITED STATES (94%)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c5"><P CLASS="c6"><SPAN CLASS="c8">LOAD-DATE: </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2">March 17, 2016</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Copyright 2016 The </SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c3">New York Times</SPAN><SPAN CLASS="c2"> Company</SPAN></P>
</DIV>'''
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(a)
soup2 = soup.select('div.c0')
list1 = [b.text.strip().encode('utf-8') for b in soup2]
print list1
var1, var2 = list1[1], list1[2]
print var1
print var2
```

Output:

```
['1 of 2 DOCUMENTS', 'The New York Times', 'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company']
The New York Times
Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company
```

Comment: Thanks. But as like previous scenario, i need the data to be stored into two different variables.say "The New York Times" into one and "Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company" into another variable as i cannot store all the data into a single list. I am going to store each variable data into a separate list

Comment: Got them in 2 variables, Check it. You must learn basics of BeautifulSoup.  The return types of various functions.

Comment: Thanks. Seems if i try to run with the above code for more HTML data, i am getting output result as Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company only for variable var2. But actually i should get both output as  Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company, Copyright 2015 The New York Times Company

Comment: If you change the data then there is no guarantee that this will work. Print the list2 and see what's there. You can extract the desired values from list2.

Comment: I think i didn't ask my question properly. Question is simple. FOr a given list.[1 of 2 DOCUMENTS', b'The New York Times', b'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company', b'2 of 2 DOCUMENTS', b'The New York Times', b'Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company'] how will first element go to one variable, second go to another variable and so on. Similarly fourth element should go to first variable and fifthe element should go to second variable and so on. The output for var1 should be['1 of 2 DOCUMENTS','2 of 2 DOCUMENTS']

Comment: Actually, i am new to Python and i am learning now. Since the task is urgent i am finding better solution to implement.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of occurrences of (in short) 'TheNYT' and 'Copyright16NYTC'?

Comment: No. I am trying to get the text of those NYT. It will come at 2nd, 4th and 6th position so on..Similarly Copyright16NYTC will come in 3rd,5th,7th and so on in a list. In that case, i need to write a code to get the values of NYT in a separate list.

Comment: `a = ['first_element','NYT','CopyrightNYT','NYT','CopyrightNYT','NYT','CopytrightNYT']
nyts = a[1:len(a):2]
copynyts = a[2:len(a):2]
print nyts
print copynyts`

Output:
`['NYT', 'NYT', 'NYT']
['CopyrightNYT', 'CopyrightNYT', 'CopytrightNYT']`

Comment: `a[1:len(a):2]` This will get all the elemnts from 2,4,6... till the end of the list. And `a[2:len(a):2]` This will get all elements from 3,5,7.... till the end of the list. Read about List slicing in python to learn about this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''... your html ...'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for x in soup.select('div.c0 br p.c1'):
    print(x.text)
```

Result

```
The New York Times
Copyright 2016 The New York Times Company
```